# Unknown Ornament Notation - Three horizontal short lines

Tags: notation, sheet-music, keyboard, organ

[image]

This nonation appears on [Partite diverse sopra l'Aria 'Schweiget mir von Weiber nehmen'](https://cn.imslp.org/wiki/Partite_diverse_sopra_l%27Aria_%27Schweiget_mir_von_Weiber_nehmen%27_(Reincken%2C_Johann_Adam)) by Reincken, Johann Adam, IMSLP #04945.

Comment: Tags harpsichord and organ may help.

Comment: Just chiming in to say I'm stumped. I've never seen it before, it doesn't appear in [this list](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm), and strangely enough it only happens the two pictured times out of a 13-page publication. I can't see a hypothesis based on the musical context either. [An original manuscript](http://conquest.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/1/13/IMSLP616990-PMLP991212-ouch_p61-p65.pdf) of another piece by Reincken shows nothing of the sort (no notated ornaments at all, in fact).

Comment: I love this kind of question. Looking forward to seeing who works it out…!

Comment: Very, very tenuto? :)

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Tenutississimo

Comment: my vote goes for the typesetter accidentally tossing ledger lines in and not bothering to fix it.

Comment: "don't even think about ornamenting this note"?

Comment: I'm gonna recruit some organ buddies on facebook... (And, for my joke answer: every web dev on the SE knows it's the "hamburger icon")

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - 1st example, feasible, 2nd not so.

Comment: To see how this is commonly performed I downloaded the pdf then found performances on youtube and spotify but they all sounded like they were playing from a different edition. So I'm none the wiser.

Comment: I wouldn't assume, just because it's above the note, that it *is* an ornament. I've toyed with the idea of it having some structural or theoretical meaning, the way one might mark a *hauptstimme* or *nebenstimme*. A Schenkerian reductionary view of the phrase would point out a scalar descension from the D to the C, and on to the cadence through B, A, and G. (But why mark just the first two...)

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS I tried a few recordings too and notice that the first three—organ, harpsichord, and modern piano—all play that D as a B. And otherwise ornament other notes than those indicated in this edition.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dolmetsch Musical Symbols guide](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) lists the **=** symbol, but not **≡**, but for = it says this:

> a symbol found above note heads in The Bird Fancyer's Delight which is explained in the original publication thus: *"The marks & rules for graceing are these Viz. a close shake thus ="*

I expect that you'd perform = similarly to ≡

Comment: in my opinion, we can listen the sound record of this sheet to reongize this ornament, or find book that talking about musical ornament?

Comment: Searching [this treatise](https://www.dolmetsch.com/Vibrato_pictures.pdf) for "close shake" shows that it meant many different things to different people. Before I got too concerned about it, I'd try to find an edition that was closer to Reinken than this 1886 one and verify that it was even in the original. Manuscripts of Reincken's other works seem to be free from notated ornaments altogether, and maybe this is just an artifact of an over-zealous editor wanting to notate an un-notated practice.